# How to extract the values from a pandas data frame column to new data frame with the help of Indexing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, interpolation

I am a learner in using pandas in python.

I have a millions of driving data signals received from Vehicle in csv format.
Example : Vehicle Speed, Brake pressure etc. at different Time intervals

Sample Data : (For reference, I used only 2 Data_Names & sample Values )

```
Time      Data_Name         Values
0.5       Vehicle_Speed     10
1         Brake_Pressure    12
2         Vehicle_Speed     30  
3         Vehicle_Speed     40
4         Vehicle_Speed     50
5         Brake_Pressure    10
6         Brake_Pressure    15
7         Vehicle_Speed     30
8         Brake_Pressure    15     
9         Brake_Pressure    20
10        Vehicle_Speed     25
```

Requirements :

1st Requirement is : I want the above data to be in the below form.

```
 Time      Vehicle_Speed_Values       Brake_pressure_Value          
    0.5       50                      0
    1         0                       12
    2         30                      0  
    3         40                      0
    4         50                      0
    5         0                       10
    6         0                       15
    7         30                      0
    8         0                       15     
    9         0                       20
    10        25                      0
```

2nd Requirement : interpolate it there by filling the zero values corresponds to time.
3rd : plotting  Vehicle_Speed (Vs) Brake Pressure graph for comparison

My code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Time Data
b1 = pd.Dataframe([0.5,2,3,4,7,25])

# Vehicle_Speed_Values       
b2 = pd.Dataframe([50,30,40,50,30,25])

# Combine two data frames
d1 = pd.concat([b1,b2], axis=1)
# Name the columns
d1.columns = ["Time","Speed"]

# Create a new data frame with column Names as Vehicle_Speed_Values& Brake_pressure_Value filled with zeros
a = pd.Dataframe([0.5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
a.columns = ["Time"]
alength = len(a["Time"])
a["Vehicle_Speed_Values"] = pd.Series(np.zeros(alength), index =a.index)
a["Brake_pressure_Value"] = pd.Series(np.zeros(alength), index =a.index)

# using for loop and index functions copy the value from d1 (data frame)to a (dataframe)

for i in range(len(d1.index)):
    if d1.Time[i] in a["Time"]:
        j = d1.Time[i]
        find_index = a.loc[a["Time"] == j].index[0]
        a.Vehicle_Speed_Values[find_index] = d1.Speed[i]
```

Problem facing :
On execution Warning message displayed.(SettingWithCopyWarnings)
Even though i get the result as expected but for large data set of 10 million values, Warning messages displayed and I cannot able to proceed further.

Requests :

I am not a good coder, any way i am sure that there will be some easy way to do the above process..
Kindly shed some light to avoid this problem or a new way to approach...

Comment: I think you just want `df.pivot('Time', 'Data_Name', 'Values').fillna(0)`, but I think your desired output is off.

Comment: Yes I got the usage of pivot. Thank you so much ....